# Storing elements of PageFactory

Tags: java, test-framework, page-factory

Hi I have many page classes with many WebElements like one of them:

```
public class DraggablePage extends BaseExtendablePage {

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href= '#tabs-1']") WebElement defaultFunctionalityTableHeader;
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href= '#tabs-3']") WebElement constraintMovementTableHeader;
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@href= '#tabs-4']") WebElement cursorStyleTableHeader;
...
```

The question is where could I store those elements? I cannot put it in another class as there is no possibility to extend because every my pageClass extends BaseExtendablePage. In the interface also no possibility to move the elements as the variables cannot be initialized.

Comment: By "store" them I assume you mean place their definitions elsewhere?  Why?  Your page objects should be granular enough to avoid duplication.  I've never had a need to store locators in a different place, it over-complicates things in my opinion.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to maintain  two seperate classes for Element adn Funtionality for a page?

Comment: Yes, exactly...